# Determining whether the map is well defined, continuous, Lipschitz, or Uniformly continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I recently had this problem on a test, but I'm not understanding how to proceed.

Let $X$ be a Banach space, and let $B_1(0)$ be the open ball about 0 in $\mathcal{B}(X)$, the space of bounded linear operators on $X$.
Define $f:B_1(0)\to B(X)$ by $$f(T)=(\mathbb{1}-T)^{-1}.$$
Then I'm asked to verify the following:

1. Show that $f$ is well defined.

Given the context of the problem I'm not sure what I'm supposed to actually verify. 
I know that since $T\in B_1(0)$, $\|T\|< 1$, so $(\mathbb{1}-T)^{-1}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}T^n$ converges. But I'm not sure what else I must show.

2. Show that $f$ is continuous wrt the operator norm topology on $B_1(0).$

If I recall correctly, it is sufficient to check if $f$ is continuous at $T=0$, which implies it is continuous on the whole domain. But I don't know how to do this.

3. Is $f$ Lipschitz or Uniformly continuous?

I know that uniform $\implies$ lipschitz, so it's sufficent to check the latter, then see what happens. But I'm not seeing what's going on here at all.

Comment: Your reasoning in 1. is incorrect. note that $f(I)$ is undefined. In 2., note that $f$ is not a linear operator.  For 3., Lipschitz is stronger than uniform.

Comment: @copper.hat, "note that $f(I)$ is undefined", but I thought $\mathbb{1}\not\in B_1(0)$?

Comment: You edited the question after my comment.

Comment: Try with $X=\mathbb{R}$ first.